# Solr: How to multisort on the field which is comma separated key:value pair

Tags: solr

Assume a scenario where we need to present solr results in the descending order on some integer field(say priority), we can easily apply "sort by priority desc".
But if this priority field is a collection of various such comma separated int priorities like search_priority,tag_priority,xyz_priority etc. 
lets say the priority field for each id in solr contains.
"search_priority:100,tag_priority:200,xyz_priority:50"
Then how will I get all ids in the descending order of tag_priority.

Note that one trivial solution is that we can make each of search_priority, tag_priority and xyz priority as an individual solr int field and then we take tag_priority desc.
But I don't want that because number of priorities may increase and we will end up adding so many solr field manually.

Is there any solr command (like multisort) which helps ordering on a comma separated text field? or any other form of concept in solr which does this will be highly appriciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using dynamic fields.

e.g. `<dynamicField name="*_priority"  type="integer"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>`

- By this you can handle any number of priority fields.
- The fields will be created dynamically and need not be defined.
- You can always use the dynamic field for sorting.